# Spring Boot 2.7.5 and Java 17: Unable to make field private static final java.lang.reflect.Method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I already read a lot of related posts. But neither helped.

I'm creating a new project.
I choose to use the lastest stable Spring Boot (2.7.5 with Spring Framework 5.3.23) and JDK (17) so far.

Spring Docs says it's compatible. They say: "Spring Boot 2.7.5 requires Java 8 and is compatible **up to and including Java 19**. Spring Framework 5.3.23 or above is also required."

But when I try to run, I got the error bellow. If I downgrade to JDK 11, it's just a warning and if I downgrade to JDK 8 it works withtout warning:

I read that a vm option could help "--add-opens" but it's not clear to me which module should I open. I tried "--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED" without sucess.

The problem is that I have a external lib and in this lib, I created a anotation "@Log" to set a local variable with an instance of the user Logger.

This annotation, uses the ReflectionUtils from spring-boot.
Then ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible is called or field.set is called. The error happens.

Can anyone help me?

```
package br.com.digihub.util.logging.annotation;

import br.com.digihub.util.logging.Logger;
import br.com.digihub.util.logging.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

@Component
public class LogAnnotationProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
    private ServletContext context;

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(final Object bean, String name) throws BeansException {
        ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(bean.getClass(), new ReflectionUtils.FieldCallback() {
            public void doWith(Field field) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
                ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
                if (field.getAnnotation(Log.class) != null) {
                    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(bean.getClass());
                    field.set(bean, log);
                }
            }
        });
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Error Log:

```
2022-10-26 17:25:25.697 ERROR 50184 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'teste': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'tenantRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tenantRepository' defined in com.example.demo.repository.TenantRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on DemoApplication: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#77e3d05' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#77e3d05': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private static final java.lang.reflect.Method jdk.proxy4.$Proxy117.m0 accessible: module jdk.proxy4 does not "opens jdk.proxy4" to unnamed module @15c43bd9
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:30) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.5.jar:2.7.5]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tenantRepository' defined in com.example.demo.repository.TenantRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on DemoApplication: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#77e3d05' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#77e3d05': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private static final java.lang.reflect.Method jdk.proxy4.$Proxy117.m0 accessible: module jdk.proxy4 does not "opens jdk.proxy4" to unnamed module @15c43bd9
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:134) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#77e3d05': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private static final java.lang.reflect.Method jdk.proxy4.$Proxy117.m0 accessible: module jdk.proxy4 does not "opens jdk.proxy4" to unnamed module @15c43bd9
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private static final java.lang.reflect.Method jdk.proxy4.$Proxy117.m0 accessible: module jdk.proxy4 does not "opens jdk.proxy4" to unnamed module @15c43bd9
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(ReflectionUtils.java:791) ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at br.com.digihub.util.logging.annotation.LogAnnotationProcessor$1.doWith(LogAnnotationProcessor.java:26) ~[util-4.0.0-plain.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:714) ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:693) ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at br.com.digihub.util.logging.annotation.LogAnnotationProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(LogAnnotationProcessor.java:24) ~[util-4.0.0-plain.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
```

Comment: can you share your class Test & TenantRepository ?

Comment: Sure. Added in the end of the post.

Comment: your repository and service looks fine. Do you have any external dependencies or configuration files? If so, please share them. Also, please share the Tenant entity class if possible.

Comment: Yes, you were right. It's a external dependency in my gradle.
I'm using a jar lib and when I remove it. It works.
But I need it. It uses the same spring boot and java version.
I still not found out how to make it works

Comment: what dependency is it? Maybe there is a newer version that supports java 17

Comment: Its a lib I created. I guess I need documentation explaining what I should do to make it compatible. I'm reading that is something related to add-opens and export.

Comment: I edited the post. I found the two lines causing the problem. But I still don't know how to solve this reflection problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you call `ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);` on JDK-internal fields that are not meant to be made accessible.

You should first check whether the field is annotated with the `Log` annotation before you call `ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);` because

- these are the only fields that need to be accessible
- these fields are in code that you control (i.e. where you can specify that the `LogAnnotationProcessor` must have access to).

A simple solution would be to just do the `makeAccessible()` call after the check:

```
@Component
public class LogAnnotationProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
    private ServletContext context;

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(final Object bean, String name) throws BeansException {
        ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(bean.getClass(), new ReflectionUtils.FieldCallback() {
            public void doWith(Field field) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
                if (field.getAnnotation(Log.class) != null) {
                    ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
                    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(bean.getClass());
                    field.set(bean, log);
                }
            }
        });
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Or even better, use the built-in filtering option from `ReflectionUtils`:

```
@Component
public class LogAnnotationProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
    private ServletContext context;

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(final Object bean, String name) throws BeansException {
        ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(bean.getClass(), new ReflectionUtils.FieldCallback() {
            public void doWith(Field field) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
                ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
                Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(bean.getClass());
                field.set(bean, log);
            }
        }, f -> f.getAnnotation(Log.class) != null);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per spring-boot github, here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/27089/files#diff-057b5902bc851e45308e000909e41e56c116987b78cfcab5c465bd601450396c

You must use `--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED` JVM options

Comment: I'm basically facing the same problem but adding this didn't help.
Here is what I've put into my build.gradle so far.......


`bootRun {
    jvmArgs += "--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED"
    jvmArgs += "--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED"
    jvmArgs += "--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED"
}`

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not a good idea to use Reflect to access non-public methods of third party libraries.